# How correct recconect to socket via angularjs service?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, sockets

I write angularjs app and have some problem. My app use socket connection to get some data every time. For this reason i write factory(code below).

```
var Service = {};
var ws = new WebSocket("url");
var timer;

Service.onMessage = function(message) { /* some code */};
Service.onClose = function() {
    timer = $interval(function () {
            ws = new WebSocket("url");
            Service.connect();
    }, 1000);
};
Service.onOpen = function() {
    console.log("open");
    if (timer) $interval.cancel(timer);
};
Service.onError = function(error) { /* some code */};

Service.connect = function() {
        // (Re)connect

        // Reattaching handlers to object
        ws.onmessage = Service.onMessage;
        ws.onclose = Service.onClose;
        ws.onopen = Service.onOpen;
        ws.onerror = Service.onError;
}
return Service;
```

And what problem i have? For simplicity lats imagine that my server is down. And socket connection is down too. After that onclose event will start. But i dont understand how to re-connect with socket. I should check connection every 1 or 5 seconds, for example. In my code if socket closed, i create new socket object and try to connect anew. And what i have? When server is up, i have many-many objects which connect to socket. Please help me. How i can fixed this, for example, to have one object(one current connect)?

Answer (score 0):

> But i dont understand how to re-connect with socket. I should check
>   connection every 1 or 5 seconds

I think this is not a pure angular related question, here a general JavaScript answer (non tested):

```
  function reconnect(url){
   ws = new WebSocket(url);
  }

  ws.onclose = function(){
   myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){reconnect('mywsURL')}, 5000);
  };
```

In angular use:

```
var interval = $interval(your_callback, 5000);
```

and to cancel the timeout:

```
$interval.cancel(interval);
```

I suggest you to read the code of this [lib](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket), really interesting.

Comment: Thanks for a lib(works fine:))! Of course may be i dont write your code correct, but instead one object, it create many objects too. When socket is close, reconnect function create new socket object which cant connect while server is down. After server is up i can see, ahah, not a magic, but tens of objects, which with smile connect to socket.
But of course lib work, and i will read(teach) source this library, thanks!!!